# Unable to pass params to AWS Lambda using Rest APIgateway

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am facing an issue while trying to pass some params lambda function through API gateway rest API. Please find the code and the error below.

**Code to Sign the request:**

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
import requests 
from pdb import set_trace as bp
method = 'POST'
service = 'execute-api'
host = 'fbyw409pah.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
region = 'ap-south-1'
endpoint = 'https://fbyw409pah.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/Ec2Create'


def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning
try:
    access_key='<access key>'
    secret_key='<secret key>'
except Exception as e:
    pass
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print('No access key is available.')
    sys.exit()

t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') 

canonical_uri = '/default/Ec2Create' 


canonical_querystring = ''


canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate+ '\n'

signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash


algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
headers = {'content_type':'application/json','x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header}
request_params = 'AMI=ami-0b84c6433cdbe5c3e&INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.micro&REGION=ap-south-1'
request_url = endpoint + '?' + request_params

print('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print(request_url)
print(headers)
print(canonical_request)
print(canonical_headers,signed_headers)
r = requests.post(request_url, headers=headers)
print('\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

---

**Lambda:**

```
import json
import boto3
import time
import base64
import datetime
AMI='<ami>'
REGION='ap-south-1'
KEY_NAME = '<mykeypair>'
def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    INSTANCE_TYPE = event["queryStringParameters"]["INSTANCE_TYPE"]
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
    instance = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        UserData = userData,
        NetworkInterfaces=[
        {'DeviceIndex': 0,'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,}]
        
    )
    
    response = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'],])
    # print("\n\t",response)
    print(response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['State']['Name'])
    while response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['State']['Name'] =='pending':
        time.sleep(5)
        response = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']])
    print(response)
    return{
        'statusCode':200,
        'body':json.dumps(response,default = myconverter)
        }
```

**Error:**

```
Response code: 403

{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/default/MLOps_EC2_Launch\n3a908c952ca6dfa0e3bb168e74608f22730249f62c1864c91614e41f31548ba0=\nhost:whogwc527k.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20210514T144212Z\n\nhost;x-amz-date\ne3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20210514T144212Z\n20210514/ap-south-1/execute-api/aws4_request\n3d3851f3641eef2f1fc5422f0b87e82f7cf7573375ac6bcb6b3b0348dc8d9a02'\n"}
```

I am able to invoke the specific lambda function without specifying any params, but my work requires some parameters to be attached to the post request so that I can specify some specifications in the Lambda Function.

Can someone please let me know how we can add QueryString params to the request?

Comment: For better understanding, can you also mention in the question the exact request params that you are sending to API. And 1 question, why you are not using body to send data ?

Comment: I am trying to pass INSTANCE_TYPE as a parameter. And to other question you have asked I am using this approach for the first time. So please guide me...

Comment: Okay, if you are using POST method, then you should send your data in body, and have you enabled lambdaproxyintegration ?

Comment: Yes it's enabled

Comment: Try sending in body and then check the event, from body you can perform `json.loads(event['body'])` to get your values

Comment: I tried to send params in the body. But getting the signature not matched error. Here is the way I am doing it. ```requests.post(request_url,data={"Instance_Type":"t2.micro"},headers=headers)```

Comment: On a different note, if I don't give any params I am successfully getting a response with event['body'] as null. The signature error is occurring when I try to include some params. So please guide me here...